# How do you spawn a child process in an external folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm using Electron.js to build a browser application that hooks up to a flask back-end located in a separate folder in the directory. As of now, I'm using a hacky work-around to exec the back-end:

```
const bat = cp.exec("cd api && python app.py");
```

however I would ideally like to spawn a back-end child process in the API folder. How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `child_process.exec()` function has a specific option for the current working directory for the child process.

You can see it in [the doc](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback).

```
child_process.exec(command[, options][, callback])

    command <string> The command to run, with space-separated arguments.

    options <Object>
        cwd <string> | <URL> Current working directory of the child process. Default: process.cwd().
        ...
```

So, you can just set that option and specify the api directory:

```
const bat = cp.exec("python app.py", {
    cwd: path.join(process.cwd(), "api")
});
```